# how can i save rdd data to local file instead of println

Tags: scala, rdd

I'd like to print rdd data using scala such as below

```
res1.foreach{case(userid,tags)=>println(s"${userid}${"\t"}${tags.topicInterests.map(_.id).mkString(",")}")}
```

And now ,i want to save the detail to local file instead of println,how can i implement it?

Comment: Try using `map` and use `saveAsTextFile`  as `res1.map{case(userid,tags)=>(s"${userid}${"\t"}${tags.topicInterests.map(_.id).mkString(",")}")}.saveAsTextFile("FILE_PATH")`

Answer (score 0):

Use `saveAsTextFile()` method of the RDD as shown below:

```
val strRdd = res1.map{case(userid,tags)=>(s"${userid}${"\t"}${tags.topicInterests.map(_.id).mkString(",")}")}
strRdd.saveAsTextFile("/home/test_user/result")
```

Note that, `saveAsTextFile` method takes a path(absolute or relative) to a folder/directory **and not a file**. The RDD data will be written as part files inside the given directory. In this case, a directory called `result` will be created with part files inside it.

There will be as many part files as the number of partitions in the `strRdd`. If the path `/home/test_user/result` already exists, your code will fail. So you will have to use a non-existing directory only.

Bonus info: The same `saveAsTextFile` method also works on other file systems like HDFS, S3 etc by taking the URL to the target directories instead of just paths.